# Nautilus 3.8 cannot store sftp passwords

Tags: gnome, nautilus, gvfs

Since Iv'e upgraded to 13.04 gnome shell, nautilus can no more store sftp passwords. 
It does not work with my existing bookmarks and with the new ones created.

Comment: From where you got gnome shell 13.04. I keep my Ubuntu up to date, but I'm still at version 3.6.3.1.

Comment: from here I think : http://ubuntugnome.org/download/

Comment: Ah, there is a big difference between [Ubuntu GNOME](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuGNOME) and [Gnome Shell](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/GnomeShell).

Comment: I don't kow if questions about Ubuntu GNOME flavor is on topic on AskUbuntu, but your problem sound more like a bug. See [How do I report a bug?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) in this sense.